# MySQL rename and overwrite an existing table

Tags: mysql, rename, alter-table

In MySQL user manual, it says the following command is way faster than the RENAME command since no table copy is required.

```
ALTER TABLE table1 RENAME TO table2;
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html

However, is there anyway that we can quickly rename/overwrite a table into an existing table in MYSQL 5.6? I have tried the following command and it shows error "You have an error in your SQL synthax;"

```
 ALTER TABLE table1 RENAME OVERWRITE TO table2;
```

Could any guru enlighten?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Not quite sure where you saw that. But ...

> `RENAME TABLE old_table TO new_table;`
>
> This statement is equivalent to
>   the following ALTER TABLE statement:
>
> `ALTER TABLE old_table RENAME new_table;`

Source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/rename-table.html

If you want to rename a table and a table with that name already exists, you need to first do.

```
DROP TABLE old_table
```

Because

> MySQL checks the destination table name before checking whether the
>   source table exists. For example, if new_table already exists and
>   old_table does not, the following statement fails as shown here:
>   (gives an example)